# Xamarin Forms Map - How to know when the map is full loaded and displayed?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I really need to know when the map is either full loaded or displayed but I cannot find anything anything about it, why?

Do you have any idea about an event or something like that?

Thank for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in Android and I am pretty sure you can find something similar in iOS.

Create custom renderer

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
```

Then

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged (e);

                if (e.NewElement != null) {
                    ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync (this);
                }
            }
public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            map = googleMap;
        }
```

Comment: I know about Android and I was wondering that it could exist for iOS and UWP. I'm working with UWP as first..

Comment: Please look at custom renderers for those systems. And next time if you know something please tell it so people don't waste time on something that you already know

Comment: But I don't know if it exists from the PCL custom object. I'm trying to code as much as I can in the PCL part and I would like to know if an event exists for that. Otherwise, if it's all about the renderer, then what would be the best idea, throw an event, call a method? I want to have a clean and optimized code

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do what you want in PCL. Maximum you can do is to use PropertyChanged event with property VisibleRegion. Not sure if it is enough for you

Comment: Ok thank you so much. By your answers and your reply, I know now how to do it, I'll check the documentation ! Thank